# const assertion with a Record type

Tags: typescript

I would like to use a const assertion for `KEYBINDINGS` (see last codeline):

```
export enum KeybindingActivity {
    SwitchTabLeft = 'switchTabLeft',
}

export type Keybinding = {
    defaultKeys: string[],
    type: TypeOfKeybinding,
}

export enum TypeOfKeybinding {
    KeySequence = 'keySequence',
    KeyCombination = 'keyCombination',
}

export const KEYBINDINGS: Record<KeybindingActivity, Keybinding> = {
    switchTabLeft: {
        defaultKeys: ['mod', 'left'],
        type: TypeOfKeybinding.KeyCombination,
    },
} as const;
```

However, the typescript compiler says

```
Type '{ readonly switchTabLeft: { readonly defaultKeys: readonly ["mod", "left"]; readonly type: TypeOfKeybinding.KeyCombination; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<KeybindingActivity, Keybinding>'.
  The types of 'switchTabLeft.defaultKeys' are incompatible between these types.
    The type 'readonly ["mod", "left"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'string[]'.(2322)
```

Is there another type than `Record<KeybindingActivity, Keybinding>` that I can use so that the const assertion works?

Thanks upfront.

Comment: add `readonly` here `defaultKeys: readonly string[],`

Comment: to get rid of the error, you could change `defaultKeys: string[]` to `defaultKeys: readonly string[]`. But does this really solve your problem? For what to do you need the const assertion?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I am trying tot ensure that neither the object itself (KEYBINDINGS) or the objects it contains can be modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want to declare a `Record` type where every property (even deeply nested ones) are `readonly`? That is possible with a `DeepReadonly` type.

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = T extends object 
  ? { readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]> } 
  : T
```

This is a recursive type and whatever gets passed into it will have every property made `readonly` and it recursively call itself for nested properties.

You would use it like this:

```
export const KEYBINDINGS: DeepReadonly<Record<KeybindingActivity, Keybinding>> = {
    switchTabLeft: {
        defaultKeys: ['mod', 'left'],
        type: TypeOfKeybinding.KeyCombination,
    },
}
```

Now the objects properties can't be mutated.

```
KEYBINDINGS.switchTabLeft.type = TypeOfKeybinding.KeyCombination // Error
KEYBINDINGS.switchTabLeft.defaultKeys.push() // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&ssl=28&ssc=54&pln=27&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwNLAJ4CMCWiAJoQOYCCAxjPgG74zZwDeAUHB3AMoDuDlACwAqAQ1wAZYADN4AXjgByAM58Yg0ROkwFAGlYBfVq1CRYcRmGCYcBYmTjy2nOEWkjkAGxhZsSgFxwSjBQZADaALp6zhbAAULYlgDyUj62JIikeobG4NDwSGhw8UkpNoTppCzsnD5cwACOyEiUVvIKANY4dY3NwLrVHD4AwhCotiI0EIgOip3YI2OEE-hT-dkmeXCUU0GYAKIAmgBCAJIAcgAi5wDiXAEXwMBgAErAIkRTHtgAPK-bUERvqlymQqDR6IwdNY8CCMgA%20OEzJycFT8YRiSQyALI5wcVxSdxeHz%20OChBSoCBEXSKDxaBSRAa4mJxBLAZLAuwZAB0w1G40miCinH0WSMMTgDyer3enx%20QkR8iECBAMCQRCUcAguAAVsBqHBqgB%20FhwKBvD6IL6kjBwQhwOYQKRFcL3R4vc2y75CUIYcKI-QGjhxIysDCHU6XG5cLmotTozQyLnixWs9llTmkHk4Bb8lbTAD0%20bgeygUGgofD5yuZ1uMdU6gxWi5%20MJ3hwSi5YGQSgEAAoAJRwQvF0vQIA)

---

#### But `readonly` is not what you think it is.

The `readonly` modifier in TypeScript is not a reliable way to prevent changes on an object. It is really easy to bypass it. Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13002). To really stop someone from mutating an object you could take a look at [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

---

Also note that `as const` does also not have the effect you think. When you declare an object with an explicit type, `as const` does not change anything. `as const` only has an effect on the type when you declare it without an explicit type.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you need the const assertion for, as some commenters have noted above.

However I'll take a guess: you want to ensure that `KEYBINDINGS` conforms to a specific index type, but you also want typescript to know the specific string literals used in `switchTabLeft.defaultKeys`

If so, you can do something like this:

```js
export enum KeybindingActivity {
  SwitchTabLeft = 'switchTabLeft',
}

export type Keybinding = {
  defaultKeys: readonly string[] // notice that a `readonly` has been added here
  type: TypeOfKeybinding
}

export enum TypeOfKeybinding {
  KeySequence = 'keySequence',
  KeyCombination = 'keyCombination',
}

// notice that the explicit type annotation is removed here
export const KEYBINDINGS = {
  switchTabLeft: {
    defaultKeys: ['mod', 'left'],
    type: TypeOfKeybinding.KeyCombination,
  },
} as const

// This line simply asserts that KEYBINDINGS conforms to the correct type
export const _keyBindingsTypeCheck: {
  [index in KeybindingActivity]: Keybinding
} = KEYBINDINGS
```

Typescript now knows that defaultKeys here is `'mod' | 'left'`

[image: Typescript knows that defaultKeys here is 'mod' | 'left']

Comment: Using the `as` keyword to assert that an object has a specific type is not a good idea. See this playground: https://tsplay.dev/m04JDm. You can easily snuggle in wrong properties. The `as` keyword tries to cast one type to another. There is only an error when both types have no overlap.

Comment: Good call @TobiasS. - updating my answer above to avoid `as`